# How can I make a collapsible div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a collapsible div the same way that a `<select>` acts like. Since you can't add an `<img>` into an `<option>`.

I tried to replicate a "language selection" box. Like this: [image: what I tried to replicate]

When you click on the dropdown box a bunch of different languages pop up. Which isn't happening on my replica. It won't expand or collapse.

Here is my code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("languageSelect");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = document.getElementsByClassName("languageContainer");
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.languageSelect {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #6bca56;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    border: none;
}

.languageSelect:hover {
    background-color: #5cae4a;
}

.selectedLanguageFlag {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 45%;
    height: 30%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0%;
    display: block;
}

.languageContainer {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #5cae4a;
    left: 0!important;
    top: 100px !important;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="languageSelect"><img class="selectedLanguageFlag" src="images/language_sk_flag.png" /></button>
<div id="languageContainer" class="languageContainer">
    <button><img src="images/language_cz_flag.png"/></button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no actual question here.  What's the issue?  What are you expecting to happen?  What is actually happening?  What do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. When I click the button the `<div>` doesn't toggle on or off.

Comment: Can you say the question or problem like what's not working?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. When I click the button the `<div>` doesn't toggle on or off.

Comment: `message: TypeError: content.style is undefined` - can you please ensure that your code is working well enough to reproduce the problem you're facing? If there are other errors generated in the question (that don't exist in your own code) that muddies the water and makes it harder to offer help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic logic to toggle the visibility of an element:

```js
const d1 = document.querySelector('.d1')
const d2 = document.querySelector('.d2')

d1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  d2.classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.d1, .d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

.d1 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.d2 {
  background: blue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">tap me</div>
<div class="d2 hidden"></div>
```

But to achieve your goal of building a language selector, there is an easier way: just use a standard `<select>`. Although you can’t add images into the options, you *can* add Unicode characters including emoji.

```css
body,select {
  color: #ddd;
}

body {
  background: #052b49;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 0.5);
  padding: 7px 2rem 7px 1rem;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 10 7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill: white" d="M 0 0 L 10 0 L 5 7 L 0 0 Z"/></svg>') no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px; 
  background-position: right 10px top 50%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option> English</option>
  <option> Français</option>
  <option> Deutsch</option>
  <option> Español</option>
  <option> Italiano</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice use of emoji; I have to admit that I hadn't thought of that approach to a solution :)